# Is ther an R function to transform a cumulative probability into a normal distribution?

Tags: r

Good morning everyone,
I have the **cumulative** probability of some data, but i want to know the **non-cumulative** probability.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you looking for kernel density estimation, i.e., do you have the data? If you only have an empirical cumulative distribution function, you would need to approximately calculate the derivative which introduces substantial uncertainty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dummy_cum <- cumsum(1:10)
​
dummy_cum

1 3 6 10 15 21 28 36 45 55
```

to reverse;

```
non_cumulative <- c(dummy_cum[1],diff(dummy_cum))

non_cumulative

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```